# How to find derivatives of $u=f(x^2+y^2+z^2)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$u=f(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$

It is so-called complicated derivative, I have never understood how to proceed with that. for example for single-variable function we just do:

$$y=f(\varphi(x)) \stackrel{\varphi(x)=u}{=} f'(u)\cdot(\varphi(x))'$$

and well, it is out of discussion, because it is very easy

for multivar function I am totally confused:

theory says it should be

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\cdot\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{}t}\ldots$$

And so on for each component.

My question is how should it look like in expanded view (like what would be $t$ here). And also what if a function has a few arguments, like $$u=f(x,y,z)$$

Any help would be very useful!

Comment: I'm not sure why your chain rule has a partial derivative with respect to $t$ in it. Assuming $x, y$ and $z$ are independent variables, let $r = r(x, y, z) = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}$. Then $u = f(r(x, y, z))$ so $$u_{x} = \frac{d f}{d r} \cdot \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = f' \cdot 2x$$ Similar reasoning will give you $u_{y}, u_{z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial derivatives are being taken through the firmulas:

for example for $x$ component:

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{f}}\cdot\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} = 2x\cdot f'$$

here $f$ is complicated so we have to take it first, then arguments.

Using simetric rule we got

$$u'_y=2y\cdot f'$$
$$u'_z=2z \cdot f'$$